# Update Row Value based on Values from same Column

Tags: sql-server

I see a lot of questions about updating columns based on other columns or tables, but haven't seen an answer about updating based on the same column but different rows.

The data layout is similar to this:

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0MV8.jpg)

I need to add a "Y" to the closed column for any row in which the row below it has a "Y" in the closed column.

So, in this example, Sequence 400 would get a "Y" in the closed column, because the row below it has a "Y".

This would only apply to rows containing the same job number.

(Background) this happens when people forget to close sequences and it results in a bunch of fake open sequences in the system. We tediously close them one by one but an SQL solution would be best.

Comment: You need to define "below". A table by definition is an unordered set. Is it safe to use the Sequence column to define order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of guessing here since there is not a lot of information provided. BTW, you should avoid using reserved words as column names. Things like Sequence are not good choices for column names.

Something like this should be close.

```
Update yt
set Closed = 'Y'
from YourTable yt
where yt.[Sequence] < (select max(Sequence) from YourTable yt2 where yt2.JobNumber = yt.JobNumber and Closed = 'Y')
```

Comment: Thanks, this is my first time asking a question so I'm not sure how many specifics to provide. I was more looking for the general method by which it would be done and work with it from there. 

Thanks a lot, I will give it a shot.

Comment: The thing is, I'm using Pervasive Control Center to access the database and I don't know how to turn the grid image into an image file for upload here. That's why I made a crude/basic copy in Excel to illustrate what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Update YT
set FLAG_CLOSED = 'Y'
FROM Job_Operations
WHERE yt.SEQ < (SELECT MAX(SEQ)FROM JOB_OPERATIONS yt2       WHERE yt2.Job=yt.Job and Flag_Closed = 'Y'

Comment: So did this work for you or not? I can't tell. If it did, you might consider marking it as the accepted answer.

Comment: I've spent the past ten minutes trying to figure out how to delete a comment. Sorry about all this. I'll provide more info once I learn how to work the site better.

Comment: Well, "YT" got a No Such Table or Object error. 

The table is Job_Operations but what is yt and yt2 supposed to be?

Comment: Update YT
    set FLAG_CLOSED = 'Y'
    FROM Job_Operations
    WHERE yt.SEQ < (SELECT MAX(SEQ)FROM JOB_OPERATIONS          yt2     WHERE yt2.Job=yt.Job and Flag_Closed = 'Y')
    and JOB = '049513'

Comment: 'Update YT
set FLAG_CLOSED = 'Y'
FROM Job_Operations

WHERE yt.SEQ < (SELECT MAX(SEQ)FROM JOB_OPERATIONS yt2 WHERE yt2.Job=yt.Job and Flag_Closed = 'Y')
and JOB = '049513''

Comment: Very sorry, trying to get the comment to display code properly.

Comment: It seems that it worked. I didn't put yt after the table name in the from clause, that's why it wasn't working.

Comment: Thanks a lot, really appreciate it. Sorry for the mess.